# ssh during low bandwidth

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ssh

I currently invoke the following ssh command over my home wifi (from OSX to Ubuntu):

```
ssh -XYC -l my_username -c arcfour,blowfish-cbc -XC my_local_server
```

This works great, except during low bandwidth situations, like if I'm streaming music over the Web, while I'm coding.

In these situations, the ssh often drops, within a minute or two.

**Is there a better setting or configuration that I can try over low-bandwidth situations?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I'm concerned about dropping connection, I use "screen" to create a virtual terminal.  That way if ssh goes down, my programs continue running and I can reconnect.

```
$ screen sudo su - userX
```

Make sure you get the identity of your session, so you can reconnect later:

```
$ screen -list
```

Should give you something like ***pid.tty.hostname***

Now if your ssh session drop, you just restart it and reconnect to you virtual terminal:

```
$ screen -r <pid>.<tty>.<hostname>
```

Check out "man screen" for more gory details.

Also - I've heard good things about "mosh" (MIT Mobile Shell), but I haven't played with it yet.
http://mosh.mit.edu/

Answer (score 1):

There's not a whole lot you can do with just SSH. You've already enabled compression. You might consider using a shorter MAC, though I'm skeptical this will help very much. For example, I use

MACs umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1

(`man ssh_config` for more details.)

But in general, SSH just doesn't do very well in situations where there are frequent packet drops. I don't know what your situation is, but maybe you can prioritize SSH traffic above your other traffic (e.g., QoS)? You may also consider something like [Mosh](http://mosh.mit.edu/), which should deal with the packet drop issue.